# How to override built-in getattr in Python?

Tags: python

I know how to override an object's getattr() to handle calls to undefined object functions. However, I would like to achieve the same behavior for the builtin getattr() function. For instance, consider code like this:

```
   call_some_undefined_function()
```

Normally, that simply produces an error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'call_some_undefined_function' is not defined
```

I want to override getattr() so that I can intercept the call to "call_some_undefined_function()" and figure out what to do.

Is this possible?

Comment: The module object has a `__getattribute__` method, but it apparently isn't used.

Comment: for what do you ever need this? ôo

Comment: I have tried overriding __getattribute__, but so far it hasn't worked:

Python 2.6b3 (r26b3:65922, Sep 12 2008, 11:22:09)

[GCC 3.4.6 20060404 (Red Hat 3.4.6-3)] on linux2

>>> def __getattribute__(obj, name):

...   print obj, name

...

>>> foo()

Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>

NameError: name 'foo' is not defined

Comment: Yes, you get an error.  But **why** are you trying to replace this function?  What possible new use case do you have in mind?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can only think of a way to do this by calling eval.

```
class Global(dict):
    def undefined(self, *args, **kargs):
        return u'ran undefined'

    def __getitem__(self, key):
        if dict.has_key(self, key):
            return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
        return self.undefined

src = """
def foo():
    return u'ran foo'

print foo()
print callme(1,2)
"""

code = compile(src, '<no file>', 'exec')

globals = Global()
eval(code, globals)
```

The above outputs

```
ran foo
ran undefined
```

Answer (score 1):

You haven't said why you're trying to do this. I had a use case where I wanted to be capable of handling typos that I made during interactive Python sessions, so I put this into my python startup file:

```
import sys
import re

def nameErrorHandler(type, value, traceback):
    if not isinstance(value, NameError):
        # Let the normal error handler handle this:
        nameErrorHandler.originalExceptHookFunction(type, value, traceback)
    name = re.search(r"'(\S+)'", value.message).group(1)

    # At this point we know that there was an attempt to use name
    # which ended up not being defined anywhere.
    # Handle this however you want...

nameErrorHandler.originalExceptHookFunction = sys.excepthook
sys.excepthook = nameErrorHandler
```

Hopefully this is helpful for anyone in the future who wants to have a special error handler for undefined names... whether this is helpful for the OP or not is unknown since they never actually told us what their intended use-case was.